# How to connect a phone with Bluetooth keyboard via Bluetooth HID profile?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

I want to design an APP that my smart phone connects to a Bluetooth keyboard. HID profile must be used.I find a lot of information about how to realize it.But still no idea.I have some questions to ask:

> 1.Does the android 4.2.2 support HID profile?
>   In the android 4.2.2 source code, I found this:
>   http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Bluetooth/res/values/config.xml
>   Is the true present that the version support HID profile?
>   If support,which version is the first support and how can I realize HID using android API? If not， how to know whether this version support HID?
>
> 2.Before this project I have realized SPP communication between two phones. I use the android API to realize SPP communicaiton,create one RFCOMM channel and specify UUID of SPP profile.I used UUID of HID instead of SPP but failed. This means that they are different to realize.Is it right?How to realize?